# What twinjet with rear-mounted engines and swept wings did I see in Savannah, GA?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

I saw this flying in Savannah, GA and need help identifying it. It looks like something military due to the color and lack of markings. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Annette. I edited the title of your question in an attempt to briefly describe the airplane you saw. Feel free to [Edit] further.

Comment: It looks like we have not yet decided between 500 and 600 !

Answer (score 21):

Gulfstream G500. The G600 is longer. The angle is close, but look at the window just ahead of the wing fairing. The original is faint but clearly ahead of the fairing curve. The G600 window is in the middle of the curve. The G600 has a bigger wing.

[image]

[G500 pinterest](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e9/c6/c7/e9c6c743d983383f05ff8362d484f218.jpg)

[image]

[G600 wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulfstream_G500/G600#/media/File:Gulfstream_G600.jpg)

Comment: Is that the G600 Lancer variant? On its way to a jousting competition?

Comment: Refueling probe :)

Comment: Flying narwal??

Comment: Airspeed probe.

Comment: "See, _this_ is how you thread the Space Needle..."

Answer (score 16):

It looks like a green Gulfstream G-650, which makes sense since Savannah is where they are made.  "Green" means unpainted (just in epoxy primer or bare metal in spots) and with no interior.  That's how corporate airplanes usually leave the factory.  Finish paint and interiors are normally custom done at completion centers selected by the purchaser.   There is a completion center across the ramp from Gulfstream, Midcoast Aviation, that probably does some of them, although as I said that's the buyer's choice.

Corporate manufacturers usually leave the completions to outside companies because the artisan level of work required doesn't dovetail well with normal production processes.  You have to have an interior with pretty much perfect joins and seams or the customer will reject it.  Bombardier starting doing Global completions in house and it was a disaster for quite a while, with customers forcing complete interior re-dos.

Answer (score 6):

It’s a G600 test article (slightly longer fuselage than a G500) undergoing a test flight in the airspace near Hilton Head Intl (KSAV) where Gulfstream’s main factory and flight test center are.  They often fly them south from KSAV to Brunswick (KBQK) for flight testing.  The aircraft is not yet certified for production, nor is the G500 either.

Answer (score 4):

That's a Gulfstream G500 or G600 (someone who knows the differences better can tell us which), probably a new one arriving to Hilton Head International for finishing at the Gulfstream service center there.  It doesn't have its final paint job yet, hence the lack of markings.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulfstream_G500/G600#Specifications This lists the differences.